# Does the scale factor evolution in a matter dominated universe allow for acceleration?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics

One probably very trivial issue which is bothering me.
Standard cosmology says that in a FRW metric, in a matter dominated flat universe (Pressure $P = 0$ and $K = 0$), the scale factor, $a \propto t^{2/3}$.

This gives $\dot{a} \propto \frac{2}{3}t^{-1/3}$ and $\ddot{a} \propto \frac{-2}{9}t^{-4/3}$.
In other words, $\ddot{a} < 0$, always.

Now, if current observations indicate that the universe is accelerating i.e. $\ddot{a} > 0$, does it imply that the good old result $a \propto t^{2/3}$ is incorrect?

Or am I interpreting something incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, all you say is perfectly correct.  The scale factor $a(t) \propto t^{2/3}$ doesn't apply to our universe.

Comment: For a flat universe with both matter and dark energy, $a\propto\sinh^{2/3}(t/t_\Lambda)$. (This neglects radiation, but radiation was important only early, not now.) You can see how this transitions from $t^{2/3}$ at small $t$ when matter dominates to exponential in $t$ at large $t$ when dark energy dominates..

Comment: Thanks everybody for all the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you quote is for a matter dominated universe, but the universe is dark energy dominated in the accelerating epoch. You could say that matter domination tried to halt expansion, but failed: dark energy started to dominate before expansion halted.